# Setting Midlet Icon using J2ME-Polish

Tags: ant, java-me, midlet, j2mepolish, jad

I'm using J2ME Polish version 2.0.7 together with ant to build my Midlet application. In order to specifcy the main-class, name and icon of the application, the J2ME Polish [documentation](http://www.j2mepolish.org/cms/leftsection/documentation/building/build.xml/build-section.html#midlet) suggests that I use the `midlet` element inside the `build` element.

```
<build usePolishGui="false" >
    <midlet name="My Killer App." icon="/logo.png" class="com.foo.MidletMain" /> 
...
</build>
```

however in the resulting .jad file only the classname is taken into account when I build my Midlet.

```
MIDlet-1: MidletMain,,com.foo.MidletMain
```

Can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See if you have the logo.png is in the root folder of the jar file

Answer (score 1):

No it must be in the info section of the j2mepolish target:

```
<project ...>
<target name="j2mepolish"  ...>
        <j2mepolish>
            <info ... icon="xxx.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is this:

```
<j2mepolish>
.....
<build>  
  ...
   <jad>
         <attribute name="MIDlet-Icon" value="/icon.png" />
   <jad>
</build>
```

Your icon would work!